# Is it possible to do this code pattern in scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

With scrapy, I want to collect urls from some pages first, then parsing each of urls found and yield the Item.

For example, the code is like this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    # collect urls first
    urls = self.collect_urls(response)

    # parse urls found
    for url in urls:
        self.parse_url(url) # will yield Item inside


def collect_urls(reponse):
    urls = response.meta.get('urls')
    if urls is None:
        urls = set()

    # do some logic of collecting urls from response into urls set
    # ...

    if is_still_has_data(response):
        # continue collecting urls in other page
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(response.url, formdata={'dummy':'dummy1'}, 
            meta={'urls': urls}, callback=self.collect_urls)
    else:
        return urls     # error here
```

The problem is I can't return object inside function that has `yield`.

Then I made the `urls` as class attribute/member like this:

```
urls = set()

def parse(self, response):
    # collect urls first
    yield self.collect_urls(response)

    # parse urls found
    for url in urls:
        self.parse_url(url) # will yield Item inside


def collect_urls(reponse):
    # do some logic of collecting urls from response into urls set
    # ...

    if is_still_has_data(response):
        # continue collecting urls in other page
        return scrapy.FormRequest(response.url, formdata={'dummy':'dummy1'}, 
            callback=self.collect_urls)
```

The problem with this code, after calling `yield self.collect_urls(response)`, it will continue directly to `for url in urls:` part instead of waiting the `collect_urls` function finished. If I remove the `yield`, the `collect_urls` function would be called only once, the callback in FormRequest doesn't function. It seems the callback only works if the FormRequest is yielded.

I know there is solution by moving the `for url in urls:` part into `collect_urls` function, but I'm wondering if it is possible to achieve code pattern that I want in scrapy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tryings, I think it's not possible to do this code pattern as the Request's callback can't return control to the original Request caller / yielder.

One of the solution I can do is I have to chain the callbacks until no urls found, then parse each of urls found:

```
def parse(self, response):
    urls = response.meta.get('urls')
    if urls is None:
        urls = set()

    # do some logic of collecting urls from response into urls set
    # ...

    if is_still_has_data(response):
        # continue collecting urls in other page
        return scrapy.FormRequest(response.url, formdata={'dummy':'dummy1'}, 
            meta={'urls': urls}, callback=self.parse)
    else:
        return self.do_loop_urls(urls)


def do_loop_urls(self, urls):
    # parse urls found
    for url in urls:
        yield self.parse_url(url) # will yield Item inside
```

Assumed there are 3 pages, the picture of process is like this:

> parse -> parse -> parse -> do_loop_urls

Comment: You know, it's best to learn to use a tool, instead of trying to retrofit it to your current way of thinking. Scrapy handle requests the way it does for better support asynchronous requests. If you really want pseudo-sync style code, you can use [scrapy-inline-requests](https://github.com/darkrho/scrapy-inline-requests).

Answer (score 0):

When you have a function that yields something, you've basically turned it into a [Python generator](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/04/07/improve-your-python-yield-and-generators-explained/), you can't really return anything anymore.

However, even if you can't return a list of items after you've yielded a Request or an Item, if you have a sequence you want to return, you can just iterate throught it and yield:

```
def some_callback(self, response):
    # ... yield something here

    requests = get_next_requests_list(response)

    # can't return requests list, so we iterate and yield:
    for req in requests:
        yield req
```

Also, Scrapy will only follow Requests and collect items that are yielded by a callback. So, if you want to trigger a callback from another callback, you have to yield the results of calling it too:

```
def some_callback(self, response):
    # ... do stuff here, yields a few items or requests

    for rr in another_callback(response):
        yield rr
```

I hope this helps clearing up your issues.

Comment: Thanks, so I guess it's not possible to do this.